# How to Create a visual studio Setup Project to install multiple Windows Services

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have 3 windows service with separate solutions. How can I install all the three with one visual studio Setup Project.

Comment: Separate solutions or separate projects?

Comment: @NicoRiff separate solutions.

Comment: if they are related and must be setup at the same time why aren't they in the same solution with different projects?

Comment: @Behzad they are not related they have their own job, but i have to install all of them in same system.

Comment: @Dutt93 the simplest way is to make another solution and put every other solution in a folder and make the installer for that solution

Comment: @Behzad thanks i will try as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why this is a difficulty, but perhaps you are stuck with the idea that the "project output" idea in a setup project means that you can have only one solution's output in a setup project.

The easiest thing to do is to create the setup project and then add (to the Application Folder) each of the service executables (which I assume have installer classes). Then add the three service executable installer classes as custom actions. To state the obvious, you allowed to have more than one custom action to install a service.